# Draw Rectangular2D using Swing on JPanel, and display the shape resizing

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I have started reading [Performing custom paint with swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). I wanted to extend what I read on the tutorial and draw rectangle "live". Not just the rectangle to pop up and show on the panel, but I wanted visually see the Rectangle shape resize as I drag the mouse, and finally when I release the mouse I wanted it to appear on the JPanel. I have included below what I did so far with a research and reading. The problem is since I am trying to catch each Rectangualr2D(this is the class I want to use) shape with mouse drag it end up looking like having a black background shape. How can I accomplish my target? Thanks for suggestions as always.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


 class RectTool  {



    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new DPanel());
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

    }

}


class DPanel extends JPanel {
    ArrayList<Rectangle2D.Double> linesBasket = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D.Double>();
    Rectangle2D.Double rect;
    final static BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(5.0f);
    double p1d ;
    double p2d;


    public DPanel() {

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        setBackground(Color.white);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                final double startPointX = e.getX(); ;
                final double startPointY = e.getY();

                //current
                rect.setRect(startPointX,startPointY,p1d,p2d);

            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){


                linesBasket.add(rect);
            }

        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){


                p1d = e.getX();
                p2d = e.getY();
                rect.setRect(10,10,p1d,p2d);
                rect.setRect(rect);

                    repaint();

            }
        });

    }

    public void repaintShapeBasket(Graphics g){
         rect = new Rectangle2D.Double();
         rect.setRect(rect);
         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;


         linesBasket.add(rect);

        for (Rectangle2D.Double rect : linesBasket) {

            g2.draw(rect);
         }
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);    

        repaintShapeBasket(g);

    } 
}
```